# Docker / Django: pipenv x requirements

Tags: django, docker

I currently setup my Django project in Docker. I used pipenv so far, therefore I don't have a requirements.txt but a pipfile. Anyone knows how I have to adjust my Dockerfile in order to install all dependencies?

I followed the [official tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/). But it doesn't say anything about pipenv, if I don't use requirements.txt - it's my case.

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very similar to pip's install:

```
ADD Pipfile /code/
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install
```

Then you'll need to activate the virtual environment in some places, I usually use:

```
source $(pipenv --venv)/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no real need for a virtual environment with a Docker container as the environment is already isolated.

You could use these lines in your Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /code
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip && python -m pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system
COPY . /code/
```

Note that pipenv is run with the "--system" option.